# Send a URI string to a model

Tags: arrays, string, model-view-controller, codeigniter, object

In CodeIgniter, I created a short URL processing function in my model that takes a URL sent by my controller as a parameter. To set the string that my model accepts I'm using the following:

```
$hash_str = end($this->uri->segments);
$fullURL = (string)"http://example.com/$hash_str";
```

When I output `$fullURL` in the controller I get the "correct" URL

```
fb($fullURL) //outputs http://example.com/3fs3A
```

but when I process this in my model I get

```
fb($fullURL) //outputs http://example.com/%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

How do I send the pre-processed string to my model or how do I get the end segment to convert correctly in my model?

Comment: What is this `fb` function? Is it a native PHP function? Never heard of it...

Comment: it's the firebug extension, firePHP

Comment: Why are you using `$this->uri->segments`? you sould be using `end($this->uri->segment_array())`.

Comment: `end($this->uri->segments)` also works, but I see it's returning an array and i'm trying to re-convert it to a string maybe this has something to do with the unidentified object when I pass it to my model, hmm..

Comment: How do you send $fullURL to your model?

Comment: @Alfonso, the regular way . . `$this->my_model->my_function($fullURL) and I receive it on the model side by my_function($input){fb($input) //outputs outputs http://example.com/%5Bobject%20Object%5D}`

Comment: You could try `print_r($input)` ... (to isolate potential problems in the FF output)

Answer (score 0):

why not write the result of your function to a var and pass that var to the model?

```
$shortcut = fb($fullURL);

$this->my_model->my_function($shortuct);

function my_function($shortcut = NULL)
{
    if(! is_null($shortcut) 
    { 
        echo $shortcut; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
      show_404(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I get what your saying about writing the results of the function to a VAR and I may try that in the future, for now I found a workaround. Btw, FB is not the function call I want to encapsulate. It's a firePHP method used for debugging info to the console.